# how to contain camera in a div in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am using camera from 'react-camera-pro' library
but the camera size on my screen only changes when I change the aspect ratio property and the camera is not getting contained in a parent container.
The camera size thus keeps changing on different devices and overflows sometimes
How to fix the size such that it is viewed in same style in all the devices?